# Third-person Steering with Samsung Gear VR Unity

Tags: c#, unity, virtual-reality

I am working on third-person steering, where you see the object like car, plane, spaceship in front of you as you steer it. I have got the code for Google Cardboard . How can I implement this in Samsung Gear VR with Unity?

```
public float speed = /* some number */;

private CardboardHead head;

void Start()
{

 head = Camera.main.GetComponent<StereoController>().Head;
```

}

```
 void Update()

 {
     transform.position += speed * head.Gaze.direction;
  }
```